# Sed replace with shell variables

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to implement sed replace with shell variables. As far for now I have working sed replace with `'`

```
sed -i -r 's#(export\ PATH=")(.*)#\1/home/USER/bin:~/.local/bin:\2#' ~/.zshrc
```

But unfortunately `'` does not expand shell variables just as stated in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5156322/675100

While trying to use `"` I keep getting problems with parentheses etc. I would like to make this generic to always use `whoami` instead of `USER`

The first attempt would be

```
sed -i -r "s#\(export\ PATH=\"\)(.*)#\1/home/`whoami`/bin:~/.local/bin:\2#" ~/.zshrc
sed: -e expression #1, char 60: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

**EDIT**

I have tried

```
sed -i -r "s#\(export\ PATH=\"\)\(.*\)#\1/home/$(whoami)/bin:~/.local/bin:\2#" ~/.zshrc
```

to escape the second group but I get the similar error :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 63: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: Note that only `$` and back-ticks cause troubles inside double quotes; parentheses are only relevant when preceded by `$` as in `$(whoami)`, etc.

Comment: You escaped the first pair of parentheses, but not the second pair around `(.*)`. That's why there is no second group that can be referenced with `\2`. Also, what's `-r` for? My copy of `sed` doesn't have that one…

Comment: why are you specifically using `/home/USER/bin` instead of `~/bin`?

Comment: @glennjackman I have tried that but zsh wouldn't recognize that correctly - I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
sed -i 's#export PATH="#&/home/'$(whoami)'/bin:~/.local/bin:#' ~/.zshrc
```

Or as @glennjackman pointed out:

```
sed -i 's#export PATH="#&~/bin:~/.local/bin:#' ~/.zshrc
```

Notice that:

- Instead of matching (start)(end) and inserting between like (start)"newstuff"(end), you can match just (start), replace it with itself using `&` and insert your "newstuff"
- To simplify the quoting, you can end the single-quoted part anytime and start a new single-quoted part later, because these are equivalent:

  ```
  echo 'hello there'
  echo 'hello'' there'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

backslash escapes are preformed within double-quotes strings, so you have to escape all the backslashes!

```
sed -i -r "s#\\(export PATH=\"\\)\\(.*\\)#\\1/home/$(whoami)/bin:~/.local/bin:\\2#" ~/.zshrc
```

I'd use one of the following to determine the user's home dir.

```
sed -i -r "s#\\(export PATH=\"\\)\\(.*\\)#\1~/bin:~/.local/bin:\\2#" ~/.zshrc
sed -i -r "s#\\(export PATH=\"\\)\\(.*\\)#\1$HOME/bin:~/.local/bin:\\2#" ~/.zshrc
sed -i -r "s#\\(export PATH=\"\\)\\(.*\\)#\1$(getent passwd $LOGNAME | cut -d: -f6)/bin:~/.local/bin:\\2#" ~/.zshrc
```

Your whole approach looks fragile.

- What if, since the PATH is already exported, I use `PATH="..."` ?
- What if I use single quotes?
- What if I use a different dot file?

Why don't you just use

```
PATH="~/bin:~/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

??

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was with the `-r` flag which used extended regular expressions.

The final solution was to use :

```
sed -i "s#\(export\ PATH=\"\)\(.*\)#\1/home/$(whoami)/bin:~/\.local/bin:\2#" ~/.zshrc
```