# match string with spaces and replace with another similar string with spaces

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file named Try1.txt that contains the string 
           "End Date       :                   "
I have a script named Try1.sh which has the string assigned to a variable
STR1="End Date       :                   "
I have a replacement string also assigned to the following variable
STR2="End Date       : Tuesday 05/06/2014"
I want to edit in place the file and replace STR1 with STR2.
I tried several different sed commands but could not figure it out.
I tried `sed -i -e "s/$STR1/$STR2/g" <Try1.txt >Try1.out.txt`
but it gives me the following error:
sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 49: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `$STR2` contains a slash `/`.

Assuming that neither `$STR1` nor `$STR2` contain an underscore, `_`, the following will work:

```
$ sed "s_${STR1}_${STR2}_g" <Try1.txt >Try1.out.txt
```

Test:

```
$ STR1="End Date     :             "
$ STR2="End Date     : Tuesday 05/06/2014"
$ echo "$STR1" > Try1.txt
$ sed "s_${STR1}_${STR2}_g" <Try1.txt
End Date     : Tuesday 05/06/2014
```

If you have no guarantee about not having underscores in your strings, the following also seems to work:

```
sed "s^A$STR1^A$STR2^Ag" <Try1.txt
```

where the three `^A`'s are entered as `Cntrl-V Cntrl-A`. (Using `\x01` doesn't work for me.)

See also, for example, [sed search and replace strings containing /](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10309968/318716) and [Sed replacement not working when using variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5156293/318716).

Comment: I tried both options but I get the following error. option not availible on this NT BASH release

Comment: @user3145909: I'm not familiar with the NT bash (seems to be based on bash 1.14.2). But I think `sed "s_${STR1}_${STR2}_g" <Try1.txt` should work on almost _any_ Unix-like shell. Do we need the `-e` switch for sed (which is often optional)?